# Uninstalling/removing special MS-Store apps from Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, windows-10-universal, windows-store

I am searching for the perfect Power Shell script to remove/uninstall special MS-Store apps from a "Windows 10" system (all releases/builds).

I could be a script for cleaning the app from the whole Windows machine or from the current Windows user profile.

Perfect would be I had both variants :-)

During the last month it seems the following variants wouldn't work always ... ?

```
Get-AppxPackage -Name "*bing*" | Remove-AppxPackage

Get-AppxPackage -Package "*Bing*" | Remove-AppxPackage

Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers -Name "*bing*" | Remove-AppxPackage

Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers -Package "*Bing*" | Remove-AppxPackage
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had to remove a few apps that were already installed, similar to your situation. I went with the get-appxpackage -allusers -package | remove method as well - thankfully, successful.

Unfortunately, once the OS is completely installed and user profiles are built, there are a few apps that are notoriously difficult to get rid of, such as Bing, Xbox, and OneDrive. The only way we were able to eliminate those apps was during the imaging process.

If that's not a viable option, I recommend attempting the uninstalls using a local admin account as opposed to a domain account as that has the highest chance of removing the apps.

If reinstall is an option, or at least blowing away the user profiles, I recommend the decrapifier:

https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/4378-windows-10-decrapifier-18xx-19xx

It can be run either during the OOBE (Out of the box experience, which is what I use on my home computer), or as a script using an OS (operating system) deployment tool. I use SCCM (System Center Configuration Manager) for deployments. As part of that, we capture a base image using MDT (Microsoft Deployment Toolkit). I've got the decrapifier set up in MDT as the final script prior to the sysprep step.

The nice thing about the script is at the top there's a nice section where you can whitelist the apps that should remain installed.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me for both existing and new users.  It's the "remove-appxpackage -allusers" that gets rid of the package permanently for future users.  I believe you need at least windows 10 1809 for this to work.  If you want the apps back, you need to get the apps iso from the vslc.  There's no -package option to get-appxpackage.

```
$list = 'Microsoft.YourPhone','Microsoft.OneConnect',
'WavesAudio.MaxxAudioProforDell2019','Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection',
'Microsoft.XboxApp','Microsoft.XboxGamingOverlay'

# system user might not have the package, so get-appxpackage -allusers
foreach ($app in $list) { 
  Get-AppxPackage $app -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers
  dir "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\$app*"  # verify it's gone
}
```